# ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh

I'm using heroku 12.04 and trying to run

```
$ git push heroku master
```

but i get the next error:

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection refused
```

if i try

```
$ ssh git@github.com
```

i get the same error

I looked for other questions on this matter and haven't figured it out yet, but this is some of the things I've checked:

1. i have openssh-server installed
2. `$ service ssh status

   ssh start/running, process 8819`
3. `$ service sshd start

   sshd: unrecognized service`
4. `$ ssh -vvv localhost

   OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012

   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *

   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

   debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.

   debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused

   ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`
5. also i tried to change in th sshd_config from port 22 to port 2222 and i still get refused to port 2222..
6. `$ sudo netstat -pantu | grep LISTEN

   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5691/dnsmasq

   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9081/sshd

   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1063/cupsd

   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1142/postgres

   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      9081/sshd

   tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1063/cupsd`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you do not need to have `openssh-server`. It is a module for allowing remote access to your computer. So, the options that you have checked are most probably not for the problem you have. Can you please add the output of the command `git config --list`

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts to generate keys deploy the heroku. I removed the toolbelt of my machine (Ubuntu) and installed manually again and added a new key .

Comment: How do you uninstall the toolbelt from ubuntu? having the same issue!

Comment: Found information detailing here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203840/heroku-trouble-uninstall-reinstall-heroku-toolbelt-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Run `ssh -v git@heroku.com` to check which ip is working

`107.21.95.3` is working for me
create config file in `~/.ssh` if you dont have `vi ~/.ssh/config：`

```
Host heroku.com
User yourusername
Hostname 107.21.95.3 
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
port 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem after I had been doing backup over ssh.

Rebooting client machine helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's help to reopen the terminal.
On mac sierra and high sierra you should need a configuration file at ~./ssh/config
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 VerifyHostKeyDNS yes     // after adding this line it start to work

Don't forget to reopen terminal and try again.